# Округление до сотых чисел из списка Python

Tags: python, список, генераторы, округление, round

```
from random import randint
import numpy as np

Series = np.random.randint(-10000, 10000, 10000)
print("Список сгенерированных чисел от -10000 до 10000 в количестве 10000 шт.: "+ str(Series))
```

Есть метод создающий список из случайных чисел от -10000 до 10000 в количестве 10000 шт. Как мне округлить полученные числа в списке до сотен?
К примеру 295->300, 1576->1600, чтобы также числа передавались в список

Comment: разделить на 100, округлить, умножить на 100

Comment: А проще сразу генерировать целые от -100 до +100 и множить на 100.

Comment: @Akina и правда :)

Comment: А ещё есть randrange, знающий про step=100.

Answer (score 1):

Вот два варианта от Akina:

1. Указание меньшего диапазона с умножением массива ndarray на 100:

```
import numpy as np
Series = np.random.randint(-100, 100, 10000) * 100
```

2. Использование randrange:

```
import random
Series = [random.randrange(-10000, 10000, 100) for x in range(100000)]
```

3. Третий вариант. В лоб (наименее эффективный, но наиболее соответствующий духу вашего вопроса):

```
Series = [round(x, -2) for x in  np.random.randint(-10000, 10000, 10000)]
```